# How can I do a "next track" command in Apollo music player using speech recognition such as utter!?

Tags: music-player, voice-recognition

I know that the Apollo music player can perform the "next track" command when requested by external programs, e.g. when connected to bluetooth devices, or when I use the "Media Button Overlay"-app. But now I would like to use utter! to do this, but I haven't found a way to configure utter!. I can configure utter! to run any command, but I do not know a command to send the "next track" command. I'd like to be able to say "next track", or "computer: next track", while driving. Any suggestions ?